# Document Ready vs Window Onload - undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm adding a small initialization function to the beginning of my script to pop up a login dialog, and I initially wanted to do it once the window was loaded, so I attempted to use the following code:

```
$( window ).onload(function() {
    console.log("foo");
});
```

However, it always returned

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

I decided to use the following code instead, and it works fine:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log("foo");
});
```

I have absolutely no problem using document ready to achieve my goals, I was just wondering why window onload would not work.

Comment: jQuery has no `onload` method. Can use `on('load')` or `load()`

Comment: you can use `$(window).load(function(){})` function for jquery

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
$( window ).onload(function() {
   console.log("foo");
});
```

is incorrect

correct will be

```
window.onload = function() {
   console.log("foo");
};
```

or

```
$( window ).load(function() {
   console.log("foo");
});
```

or

```
$( window ).on('load', function() {
   console.log("foo");
});
```

----- edit -----

if you are using jQuery i would recommend ["ready" function](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   console.log("foo");
});
```

or short version

```
$(function() {
   console.log("foo");
});
```

Comment: thanks for including the full trifecta of on loads :-)

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean `window.onload`, that is a javascript event

```
window.onload = function(){
  // x functionality when window loads
}
```

`$(window).load` is a similar event in jQuery. `$(document).ready` is jQuery for when the DOM is ready and loaded.

For a bit of trivia: The `$(document).ready` is actually the first of the above events to fire, as this doesn't wait for images (etc.). It fires directly after the DOM has loaded. The other two wait until the whole page is loaded.

Comment: Just as a note: If you do `$(window).load(function(){})` **after** the content was loaded the callback will not be called.  On the other hand `$(document).ready(function(){})` will be called when the DOM is ready and if the DOM is already ready at that time then it will be called immediately.

Answer (score 1):

```
window.onload = function() {

};
```

this is not jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Window.load fires when everything in the page has finished loading. That means that not only the entire DOM is loaded, but any linked resources such as images are fully loaded. Because this waits for images to finish loading, it can sometimes take a long time to fire.

See the below code which will fire the window load event after the image load function so  you can use the document.ready event if you want to intervene "early" in the rendering process, without waiting for the images to load.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){        
            $("img").load(function(){
            alert("Image loaded.");
        });
   });
$(window).load(function(){
   alert('load my window when all the resources on the page is loaded');
});
</script>
 <html>  
  <head>    

</head>
<body>
<img src="img_moustiers-sainte-marie.jpg" alt="Cinqueterra" width="304" height="236">

<p><b>Note:</b> Depending on the browser, the load event may not trigger if the image is cached.</p>
</body>
</html>
```